# Is there any undo command when editing any field

Tags: 2.2-froyo, editing

When editing text fields, is there an **UNDO** command ?

If you paste something in a text field by accident, the only way you can delete this, is to backspace over it ( or highlight and cut ).

So I was wondering whether there was an UNDO command I haven'f found yet.

I am running Froyo on a Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: It seems there is not, star this issue and pray that it gets Google's attention: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6458

Comment: @Lie Ryan: added my request to the issue . Thanks.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Maybe you should repost this as an answer?

Comment: @onik: I've reposted it as an answer

Comment: Dang, 2+ years on and Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean and there is still no common UNDO (Ctrl+Z like) feature?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems there is not, star this issue and pray that it gets Google's attention: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6458