# There is an Android equivalent to Microsoft's CTRL+Z?

Tags: editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any undo command when editing any field](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/is-there-any-undo-command-when-editing-any-field)

Today I just make a mistake when typing a text on a box over Android's browser and then I realise that I was missing the "back to past" CTRL+Z Microsoft Windows feature, which allows you to step back anything you made on Windows. So, there is such thing on Android OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The back button serves as Undo or Cancel (or Back) in many apps, but won't help with a typo in a text box, it's more likely to lose everything you've typed in there than undo the last bit of typing.

I don't believe that there's any standard, central Undo function in Android at the moment. As very few devices have a hardware keyboard, and many devices are starting to drop even the four hard buttons, I'm not sure how Undo could easily be invoked/shown to the user. Ctrl/Alt etc key combos obviously aren't practical on a soft keyboard on a 4 inch touchscreen, and I'm not sure how else it would be done except with a dedicated undo button on the phone or the soft-keyboard.