# How can I emulate ctrl-Z (undo) in Android 4.1.2 on a Galaxy Note 3?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, text-editor, keyboard-shortcuts, text-input

Based on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/is-there-any-undo-command-when-editing-any-field) and [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13284/there-is-an-android-equivalent-to-microsofts-ctrlz) and [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6458), it sounds like Android basically doesn't have undo/redo functionality. (I guess? Correct me if I've misunderstood or if the situation has changed.)

My goal is to use a Galaxy Note 3 with an external keyboard to work on long-form writing projects.

I'd like to have undo/redo functionality.

Is there some way to "bolt it on?"

Like maybe is there a text editor that has undo/redo as a feature, or some app that lets you add it, or a trick you can do an automation utility or something?

(It doesn't actually have to be `ctrl-Z`. Any reasonably convenient keypress would be fine.)

Comment: If the Android OS system doesn't allow to undo actions (other than some special Toasts allow e.g. in Gmail when you delete a message), you can't expect that just by connecting an external keyboard will circumvent this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this via a search I found these options...

- Polaris Office's word processing program implements undo that works via `control-Z` on my Galaxy Note 3 using a Bluetooth keyboard.
- The [JotterPad X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x) text editor implements undo and redo that works fine via on-screen controls.

  The JotterPad X app description on the Google Play store claims specifically...

  > Compatible with physical and Bluetooth keyboard including shortcut keys (E.g. ctrl + Z for undo)

  On my system, JotterPad X's undo didn't work with a Bluetooth keyboard, but maybe it will work on your system or with a different model keyboard.